# Use of article 'the' before author's name

Tags: articles

Is is correct to write: 'Author Martin Amis describes...', or should we use the article 'the' in front of 'author'?

Answer (score 4):

"The" is not required.

There are many examples where a profession is prefixed to a name. For example:

> Driver Lewis Hamilton came in first once again.

However, I'm quite sure that it is context dependent. For example, let us say we are talking about your author describing a door.

> Author Martin Amis describes the door as unbreakable.

is slightly different to

> The author, Martin Amis, describes the door as unbreakable.

So pick whichever one you need.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, but I think the difference is one of formality. *Author Martin Amis* might be found in a popular newspaper, but a piece of academic prose would be more likely to refer to *the author Martin Amis*, assuming it wasn’t enough simply to write his name alone.

Comment: I agree here, but Kate's point is valid. I'd not use 'The sheep Dolly' / 'Sheep Dolly' as an example because she's probably as much 'Dolly the Sheep' as Shaun is 'Shaun the Sheep' and Donald isn't 'Donald the Duck'. There seems to be a rule-of-thumb (I'm sure there are exceptions) that humans can take the article or leave it ((The) author Steven Goldin) except when it's a title (King John), animals need the article (The racehorse Arkle), and inanimates are mixed (Hurricane Sandy but The frigate 'Unicorn'). Proper names are part of the chaos: Lake Victoria, but the River Thames.

Comment: Thinking a little further - there seems to be a conferring of respect when _the_ is used before a profession - _the architect, Robert Sykes_ but _dustman Robert Sykes_. This is perhaps not the case with _the outlaw Jesse James_.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. It is possible to make mischief by playing around with articles in such cases, in a way that writers in ‘The Economist’ sometimes seem to do. They are capable of referring to ‘Edward Heath, a former prime minister’ (although not an authentic example).

Comment: There's a political protocol as well when it comes to whether an expression should be considered titular or in apposition. Princess X but Y, Princess ... . President A but Mr B. the Prime Minister. I think we had to call the Queen's late mum 'Queen Elizabeth, the Queen Mother' too.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. To the inner circle, she was always just _Queen Elizabeth_. Elizabeth II is _The Queen_, capital T.

Comment: She's not under that in the phone book.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a property of a word whether it can be used this way or not. Compare:

> Author Kate Gregory recommends C++ AMP because ...

and

> Sheep Dolly was cloned...

Author can be anarthrous and sheep can't. Just about every profession a person can hold is ok to use without "the" and as for all the other nouns in English, I don't think there's really a rule. Off the top of my head, all the examples I can find are nouns describing something a person is. I mean that nouns like table, blizzard, whisper, and so on can't be used like this, while schoolboy, housewife, candidate, and so on all can. But I'm not sure that's a rule, it might just be that my imaginary sentence generator is slow this morning.

Oh:

> Hurricane Sandy swept into New York

Not sure why that's ok and Sheep Dolly isn't.

Comment: 'Hurricane Sandy swept into New York' is a headline, and articles are frequently dropped in headlines. If Sheep Dolly appeared in a headline it, too, could be anarthrous: 'Sheep Dolly Dies'.

Comment: Agreed that both headlines and newspaper-quoting style are muddying my "sounds right" sense, but "_According to X_, something" or "_As far as X is concerned_, something" both feel ok with Profession Name and Hurricane Sandy, but wrong with Sheep Dolly.

Comment: 'Hurricane Sandy swept into New York' is the way you'd probably say it in ordinary conversation, as well as being headlinese - although I'd expect _sweeps_. Ok, in conversation, you might well change 'swept into' to _reached_ or _hit_, but that's non-germane.